# Zooming UIImage in a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I currently have a custom class that implements UIScrollView.

I created one UIImageView and add it to a subview of the UIScrollView.  It scrolls vertically and horizontally perfectly, but it seems to be ignoring the zooming stuff.  Here is my code:

```
- (void) setUpBoard
{
    // add board
    UIImageView *imageHolder = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grid.jpg"]];
    [self addSubview:imageHolder];
    self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageHolder.frame.size.width, imageHolder.frame.size.height);
    self.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    self.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
    self.minimumZoomScale = 0.2;
    self.zoomScale = 0.7;
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

How do I get it to zoom using standard pinch gestures? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [*UIScrollView Class Reference* Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1):

> The `UIScrollView` class can have a delegate that must adopt the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol. For zooming and panning to work, the delegate must implement both `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` and `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:`; in addition, the maximum (`maximumZoomScale`) and minimum (`minimumZoomScale`) zoom scale must be different.

I suspect that either you haven't assigned a delegate to the scroll view, or the delegate doesn't implement both of those methods.

Comment: I'm still a newbie and am not sure how implement the delegate.  In my header file, I have `@interface ASScrollBoard : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate>`

The in my implementation file, I have implemented the two methods `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` and `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:`

For the first, I'm returning 'self' as the UIView.  What else am I missing here?  Thanks.

Comment: If you want the scroll view to be its own delegate, you need to set it, by doing `self.delegate = self` in some initialization method (like `setUpBoard`).  You also need to store the image view in an instance variable so you can return it in `viewForZoomingInScrollView:`.  Your `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:` method can be empty.